# Using sp.create_contract to generate pseudorandom numbers on-chain

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

[In this answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3559/6002), the answerer suggested that CREATE_CONTRACT could be used to generate a contract address which could then be used as a seed for a pseudorandom number in a contract.

**What would a simple example of this look like when using Smartpy?**

For context, my end goal would be to provide an endpoint that receives payment, generates a pseudo-random number (via the above method) and then mints an NFT with attributes based partially on the random result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the example provided by Rafael, you can do the following in SmartPy.

```
import smartpy as sp

class Creator(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(address = sp.none)
        
    @sp.entry_point
    def generate_address(self):
        # Generate the address but don't append the operation
        contract = sp.create_contract_operation(sp.Contract(), sp.unit, sp.tez(0), None);
        self.data.address = sp.some(sp.pack(contract.address))
        
@sp.add_test(name = "generate_address")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    c1 = Creator()
    scenario += c1
    c1.generate_address()
```

`this.storage.address` will contain the "random" value.

Something similar to: `0x050a0000001601294ce4766fe8c9a9aa375b5413de86998127ffd100`

Comment: How would you convert this to a sp.nat though?

Comment: @Daniel This q has a working example of converting a hash to a nat: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/converting-a-hash-into-an-int-within-a-range

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I ended up doing it. NOTE: this is not at all truly random do not use this for any purposes other than a very very weak random number generator with no funds associated with the output

```
def get_random(self):
    ha = sp.bytes("0x")
    bytes_to_nat = sp.local('bytes_to_nat',{})
    bytes_to_nat.value = {
            sp.bytes('0x00'): 0, sp.bytes('0x01'): 1,
            sp.bytes('0x02'): 2, sp.bytes('0x03'): 3,
            sp.bytes('0x04'): 4, sp.bytes('0x05'): 5,
            sp.bytes('0x06'): 6, sp.bytes('0x07'): 7,
            sp.bytes('0x08'): 8, sp.bytes('0x09'): 9,
            sp.bytes('0x0a'): 10, sp.bytes('0x0b'): 11,
            sp.bytes('0x0c'): 12, sp.bytes('0x0d'): 13,
            sp.bytes('0x0e'): 14, sp.bytes('0x0f'): 15,
            sp.bytes('0x10'): 16, sp.bytes('0x11'): 17,
            sp.bytes('0x12'): 18, sp.bytes('0x13'): 19,
            sp.bytes('0x14'): 20, sp.bytes('0x15'): 21,
            sp.bytes('0x16'): 22, sp.bytes('0x17'): 23,
            sp.bytes('0x18'): 24, sp.bytes('0x19'): 25,
            sp.bytes('0x1a'): 26, sp.bytes('0x1b'): 27,
            sp.bytes('0x1c'): 28, sp.bytes('0x1d'): 29,
            sp.bytes('0x1e'): 30, sp.bytes('0x1f'): 31,
            sp.bytes('0x20'): 32, sp.bytes('0x21'): 33,
            sp.bytes('0x22'): 34, sp.bytes('0x23'): 35,
            sp.bytes('0x24'): 36, sp.bytes('0x25'): 37,
            sp.bytes('0x26'): 38, sp.bytes('0x27'): 39,
            sp.bytes('0x28'): 40, sp.bytes('0x29'): 41,
            sp.bytes('0x2a'): 42, sp.bytes('0x2b'): 43,
            sp.bytes('0x2c'): 44, sp.bytes('0x2d'): 45,
            sp.bytes('0x2e'): 46, sp.bytes('0x2f'): 47,
            sp.bytes('0x30'): 48, sp.bytes('0x31'): 49,
            sp.bytes('0x32'): 50, sp.bytes('0x33'): 51,
            sp.bytes('0x34'): 52, sp.bytes('0x35'): 53,
            sp.bytes('0x36'): 54, sp.bytes('0x37'): 55,
            sp.bytes('0x38'): 56, sp.bytes('0x39'): 57,
            sp.bytes('0x3a'): 58, sp.bytes('0x3b'): 59,
            sp.bytes('0x3c'): 60, sp.bytes('0x3d'): 61,
            sp.bytes('0x3e'): 62, sp.bytes('0x3f'): 63,
            sp.bytes('0x40'): 64, sp.bytes('0x41'): 65,
            sp.bytes('0x42'): 66, sp.bytes('0x43'): 67,
            sp.bytes('0x44'): 68, sp.bytes('0x45'): 69,
            sp.bytes('0x46'): 70, sp.bytes('0x47'): 71,
            sp.bytes('0x48'): 72, sp.bytes('0x49'): 73,
            sp.bytes('0x4a'): 74, sp.bytes('0x4b'): 75,
            sp.bytes('0x4c'): 76, sp.bytes('0x4d'): 77,
            sp.bytes('0x4e'): 78, sp.bytes('0x4f'): 79,
            sp.bytes('0x50'): 80, sp.bytes('0x51'): 81,
            sp.bytes('0x52'): 82, sp.bytes('0x53'): 83,
            sp.bytes('0x54'): 84, sp.bytes('0x55'): 85,
            sp.bytes('0x56'): 86, sp.bytes('0x57'): 87,
            sp.bytes('0x58'): 88, sp.bytes('0x59'): 89,
            sp.bytes('0x5a'): 90, sp.bytes('0x5b'): 91,
            sp.bytes('0x5c'): 92, sp.bytes('0x5d'): 93,
            sp.bytes('0x5e'): 94, sp.bytes('0x5f'): 95,
            sp.bytes('0x60'): 96, sp.bytes('0x61'): 97,
            sp.bytes('0x62'): 98, sp.bytes('0x63'): 99,
            sp.bytes('0x64'): 100, sp.bytes('0x65'): 101,
            sp.bytes('0x66'): 102, sp.bytes('0x67'): 103,
            sp.bytes('0x68'): 104, sp.bytes('0x69'): 105,
            sp.bytes('0x6a'): 106, sp.bytes('0x6b'): 107,
            sp.bytes('0x6c'): 108, sp.bytes('0x6d'): 109,
            sp.bytes('0x6e'): 110, sp.bytes('0x6f'): 111,
            sp.bytes('0x70'): 112, sp.bytes('0x71'): 113,
            sp.bytes('0x72'): 114, sp.bytes('0x73'): 115,
            sp.bytes('0x74'): 116, sp.bytes('0x75'): 117,
            sp.bytes('0x76'): 118, sp.bytes('0x77'): 119,
            sp.bytes('0x78'): 120, sp.bytes('0x79'): 121,
            sp.bytes('0x7a'): 122, sp.bytes('0x7b'): 123,
            sp.bytes('0x7c'): 124, sp.bytes('0x7d'): 125,
            sp.bytes('0x7e'): 126, sp.bytes('0x7f'): 127,
            sp.bytes('0x80'): 128, sp.bytes('0x81'): 129,
            sp.bytes('0x82'): 130, sp.bytes('0x83'): 131,
            sp.bytes('0x84'): 132, sp.bytes('0x85'): 133,
            sp.bytes('0x86'): 134, sp.bytes('0x87'): 135,
            sp.bytes('0x88'): 136, sp.bytes('0x89'): 137,
            sp.bytes('0x8a'): 138, sp.bytes('0x8b'): 139,
            sp.bytes('0x8c'): 140, sp.bytes('0x8d'): 141,
            sp.bytes('0x8e'): 142, sp.bytes('0x8f'): 143,
            sp.bytes('0x90'): 144, sp.bytes('0x91'): 145,
            sp.bytes('0x92'): 146, sp.bytes('0x93'): 147,
            sp.bytes('0x94'): 148, sp.bytes('0x95'): 149,
            sp.bytes('0x96'): 150, sp.bytes('0x97'): 151,
            sp.bytes('0x98'): 152, sp.bytes('0x99'): 153,
            sp.bytes('0x9a'): 154, sp.bytes('0x9b'): 155,
            sp.bytes('0x9c'): 156, sp.bytes('0x9d'): 157,
            sp.bytes('0x9e'): 158, sp.bytes('0x9f'): 159,
            sp.bytes('0xa0'): 160, sp.bytes('0xa1'): 161,
            sp.bytes('0xa2'): 162, sp.bytes('0xa3'): 163,
            sp.bytes('0xa4'): 164, sp.bytes('0xa5'): 165,
            sp.bytes('0xa6'): 166, sp.bytes('0xa7'): 167,
            sp.bytes('0xa8'): 168, sp.bytes('0xa9'): 169,
            sp.bytes('0xaa'): 170, sp.bytes('0xab'): 171,
            sp.bytes('0xac'): 172, sp.bytes('0xad'): 173,
            sp.bytes('0xae'): 174, sp.bytes('0xaf'): 175,
            sp.bytes('0xb0'): 176, sp.bytes('0xb1'): 177,
            sp.bytes('0xb2'): 178, sp.bytes('0xb3'): 179,
            sp.bytes('0xb4'): 180, sp.bytes('0xb5'): 181,
            sp.bytes('0xb6'): 182, sp.bytes('0xb7'): 183,
            sp.bytes('0xb8'): 184, sp.bytes('0xb9'): 185,
            sp.bytes('0xba'): 186, sp.bytes('0xbb'): 187,
            sp.bytes('0xbc'): 188, sp.bytes('0xbd'): 189,
            sp.bytes('0xbe'): 190, sp.bytes('0xbf'): 191,
            sp.bytes('0xc0'): 192, sp.bytes('0xc1'): 193,
            sp.bytes('0xc2'): 194, sp.bytes('0xc3'): 195,
            sp.bytes('0xc4'): 196, sp.bytes('0xc5'): 197,
            sp.bytes('0xc6'): 198, sp.bytes('0xc7'): 199,
            sp.bytes('0xc8'): 200, sp.bytes('0xc9'): 201,
            sp.bytes('0xca'): 202, sp.bytes('0xcb'): 203,
            sp.bytes('0xcc'): 204, sp.bytes('0xcd'): 205,
            sp.bytes('0xce'): 206, sp.bytes('0xcf'): 207,
            sp.bytes('0xd0'): 208, sp.bytes('0xd1'): 209,
            sp.bytes('0xd2'): 210, sp.bytes('0xd3'): 211,
            sp.bytes('0xd4'): 212, sp.bytes('0xd5'): 213,
            sp.bytes('0xd6'): 214, sp.bytes('0xd7'): 215,
            sp.bytes('0xd8'): 216, sp.bytes('0xd9'): 217,
            sp.bytes('0xda'): 218, sp.bytes('0xdb'): 219,
            sp.bytes('0xdc'): 220, sp.bytes('0xdd'): 221,
            sp.bytes('0xde'): 222, sp.bytes('0xdf'): 223,
            sp.bytes('0xe0'): 224, sp.bytes('0xe1'): 225,
            sp.bytes('0xe2'): 226, sp.bytes('0xe3'): 227,
            sp.bytes('0xe4'): 228, sp.bytes('0xe5'): 229,
            sp.bytes('0xe6'): 230, sp.bytes('0xe7'): 231,
            sp.bytes('0xe8'): 232, sp.bytes('0xe9'): 233,
            sp.bytes('0xea'): 234, sp.bytes('0xeb'): 235,
            sp.bytes('0xec'): 236, sp.bytes('0xed'): 237,
            sp.bytes('0xee'): 238, sp.bytes('0xef'): 239,
            sp.bytes('0xf0'): 240, sp.bytes('0xf1'): 241,
            sp.bytes('0xf2'): 242, sp.bytes('0xf3'): 243,
            sp.bytes('0xf4'): 244, sp.bytes('0xf5'): 245,
            sp.bytes('0xf6'): 246, sp.bytes('0xf7'): 247,
            sp.bytes('0xf8'): 248, sp.bytes('0xf9'): 249,
            sp.bytes('0xfa'): 250, sp.bytes('0xfb'): 251,
            sp.bytes('0xfc'): 252, sp.bytes('0xfd'): 253,
            sp.bytes('0xfe'): 254, sp.bytes('0xff'): 255
        }
    nat_value = 0
    contract = sp.create_contract_operation(sp.Contract(), sp.unit, sp.tez(0), None);        
    # Convert given string (as bytes) to sha256 hash
    b = sp.pack(contract.address)
    ha = sp.sha256(b)
    # Iterate over each byte of the hash and look up the corresponding int value from our big table above
    x = sp.local('x', 0)
    # Store the 'total' Nat value of the bytes
    total = sp.local('total', 0)
    hash_len = sp.local("hash_len", sp.len(ha))
    sp.while x.value < hash_len.value:
        # Add to previous total and then multiple the new value by 256
        total.value = (total.value + bytes_to_nat.value.get(sp.slice(ha, x.value, 1).open_some())) * 256
        sp.if total.value >= 1000000000000000:
            x.value = 1000000000000000
        sp.else:
            x.value = x.value + 1
    num = (total.value // 10)
    return num
```

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing how the create_contract call generates the hash returned and how deterministic it is. Bonus points for explaining how easy/hard it would be to exploit it.