# How to get randomness for my game?

Tags: smart-contracts

Let's say a player encounters an enemy on a grid-based game, how can I generate a random number on chain to generate the enemy basic characteristics ( HP, strength, agility... ) at the time of the attack? Or the amount of a treasure contained in a chest?

[According to this answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3564/using-sp-create-contract-to-generate-pseudorandom-numbers-on-chain?rq=1) and [this implementation by Asbjornenge](https://github.com/asbjornenge/tezos-randomizer) one way is to originate a contract and use its address as a seed to get randomness, and provides entropy using Harbinger Oracle. How is this address generated and how predicatble is it?

Is there a faster/safer/better/less predictable way to get randomness on chain if the game manages a great amount of ꜩ, or should I go with Asbjornenge's implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Acurast data providers](http://docs.acurast.com/integrations/tezos/) to generate secure random bytes from inside a [TEE](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/trusty)(Trusted Execution Environment)

How does it work?

You schedule a job in this [contract](https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1MFfBe4EtzDofUcfeBmNShJPesY4HhfjMC/storage) where you provide the script for generating the random bytes and a few other job configurations, like the destination contract(Your game).

Currently, the jobs can only be registered by the administrator. Let me know if you are interested, I can put you in contact with the developers.

The job will look like this:
[image]